# Wiring for 30amp RV plug from 50amp (14-50R) outlet

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

When building our home, I pre-wired for a 50amp electric car outlet using a 6/2 wire (not 6/3 because according to Tesla charging station, they only need 6/2. 6/3 wire was going to cost me $20 more - oh man... ). We bought an RV that accepts 30amp using TT-30P.

The RV came with a 50amp to 30amp converter and I have a 50 amp (14-50R) ready to install.

Can I install a 14-50R knowing that only three wires are going to be used during the conversion to a 30amp TT-30P?

Does the 50amp need to be a wired as 3 pole or wire as a traditional 110v (one hot, the other neutral)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is switching out the receptacle and breaker for this circuit an option?

Comment: Yes, after some time, it seems like thats the only option. I changed out the breaker to a single pole 30 amp and changed out the receptacle. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Post that as an answer and I'll give you an upvote for it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sophie's choice: One way, you fry half the appliances in the RV... The other way, you electrify the chassis of the RV.  Whoops!    The only other possibility with a 6/2 cable is to hook up neutral and ground properly, then *not hook up* one of the hot wires, but this too is bad (just less destructively).

The only way to support a 14-50 with 6/2 is to add a 12 KVA transformer to the mix.

But why bother? You don't benefit from a 14-50. You benefit from a TT30, which is the plug your RV actually does have.

That's a much simpler matter.

- Change the 50A 2-pole breaker to a 30A 2-pole* breaker.
- Move the white wire from the breaker to the neutral bar.   Very important!
- Throw the NEMA 14-50 recep on the shelf. You will not be using it today.
- Install a TT30 receptacle.
- Enjoy your RV.

Now, you may find the breaker or recep will not accept a #6 wire.  In that case you'll need to pigtail a #10 wire onto it. The big blue wire nuts should suffice. Crank Hard.  No... HARD!

---

---

* Mind you, you don't actually *need* a 2-pole breaker, but you do need to fill the empty space, so a 2-pole breaker takes care of that.  Also, 30A 1-pole breakers are essentially useless for any purpose but TT30 RV outlets. 30A 2-pole breakers are used for all sorts of things.

Comment: Thanks that was it. I replaced the 50amp breaker to a single pole 30 amp. And wired the tt30 plug and there it was. I was hoping to keep it a 50amp so it could be expandable to other applications like a big welding unit (i dont know anything about welding) or other heavy duty appliances. This will work for now and if I need 220v 50amp in future, I will just replace the plug.